# Prototype objects and "Per Graph" DI Lifecycle

Tags: c#, .net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I've got a `Credentials` class that should be provided through dependency injection as an instance to all constructors which need it.  Currently I've solved this problem by registering a single instance of the class to my DI container, with a singleton lifecycle.  This ensures, per DI invocation, that all objects receive the same credentials.  This works, but is a little awkward because the properties of the `Credentials` singleton will change between each explicit DI invocation.  This means each recipient constructor must immediately "grab and save" credentials properties from the `Credentials` instance before they change.

What would make this better is if I could get the DI container to create a new `Credentials` instance, per-graph or per-invocation, that is based on a prototype object (yes, GOF "Prototype" pattern).  I am using Simple Injector, so my first solution looks like this:

```
public static Credentials creds; //Implements ICloneable

//....

var prototypeTransientLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateCustom(
    name: "Prototype Transient",
    // instanceCreator is of type Func<object>
    lifestyleApplierFactory: instanceCreator =>
    {
        return () => creds.Clone();
    });
```

I think this works but, even so, it has two weaknesses.  First, it can only be applied to my `Credentials` class.  I'd like it to be generically reusable.  Second, it creates potentially many clones within a single, explicit DI invocation.  I'd like it to have "per-graph" lifecycle so that it creates the clone just once and re-uses it for the remainder of that DI invocation.

Any ideas of how to proceed?

Incidentally, I know that "per-graph" lifecycle suffers from problems associated with lazy evaluation.  I don't have any lazy evaluation, so it is not a concern.

### Update

I think I have a partial solution to my problem.  To achieve the prototype cloning in a generic fashion, I can do this:

```
container.Register<Credentials>(() => (Credentials)creds.Clone());
```

Now I'd still like to have the "per graph" behavior.  Further reading suggests I need to use a Simple Injector `Scope`.  Apparently this requires that I have a central location where my DI container is invoked, so that I can explicitly create the scope.  My code is indeed well-suited for that, but I'm still wondering if there is another way to achieve "per graph" which does not require explicitly creating a scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [noted](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#pergraph) in the documentation, Simple Injector has no notion of a "per graph" lifestyle. Instead, the Scoped lifestyle provides behavior which is usually close enough.

> Apparently this requires that I have a central location where my DI container is invoked, so that I can explicitly create the scope.

That is correct. This central location is called the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) and every application will have it.

> I'm still wondering if there is another way to achieve "per graph" which does not require explicitly creating a scope.

The Simple Injector GitHub repository contains [a code example that demonstrates the Per Graph lifestyle](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples/PerGraphLifestyle.cs), but my advise is to stick with the built-in construct, namely the `ScopedLifestyle`.